# AdBanner white space when loading view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, adbannerview

I have an ad banner on a UIView which is showing white space when view is first loaded.  I

have implemented the delegate methods and they get called and the banner works fine.  It is

just when the view loads initially and the ad fails for the first time, the app displays a

white space and the delegate methods don't get called. `Anyone encountered this?`

Comment: posting the ad banner code specially the error part which deals with the ad fail to appear section would be helpful. what ios are you using? have you look at the latest i ad sample projects that work with iOS 6 if you are using iOS 6?

Comment: Thanks, I have set the alpha on the Banner View to 0 initially which resolved the problem.  I then fade the banner in and out.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Step 1 : add iAd.framework to your project
// Step 2 : #import <iAd/iAd.h>
// Step 3 : ADBannerViewDelegate to your viewController
// Step 4 : Initialize your adBanner in your viewDidLoad Method
    myIad = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
    [myIad setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, myIad.frame.size.width, myIad.frame.size.height)];
    [myIad setDelegate:self];

// Step 5 : Implement following Delegate method to show and hide your bannerView

#pragma mark - AdBanner Delegate
- (void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    // Show Add Banner
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
        [banner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-banner.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Hide with animation as failed to load ad
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
        [banner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }];
}
```